# Magento - Downloadable products with guest checkout support?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Greetings

I’m having a bit of trouble with the guest checkout system and downloadables. I know that in magento it says that guest checkout will only work with shareable items. Unfortunately none of my products will be shareable.

I would like users to be able to checkout as a guest, receive an email with a download link, and download the product. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I decided to go ahead and turn on Shareables.  It's actually working pretty well.  It even supports expiring download links. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2):

register them as users on the go and generate a password for them automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can go to system > configuration > Catalog > Donwloadble Products and change (Disable Guest Checkout if Cart Contains Downloadable Item) to No.

[image]